# How do I specify an optional prop in the returned React$Element in Flow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, types, flowtype

I have a React component that, based on which prop it receives, might return either a non-clickable `div` (i.e., without an `onClick`-prop) or a clickable `button` (i.e., with an `onClick`-prop). How do I specify this in the Flow type annotation?

I used to use `?React$Element<*>` as the return type, but that didn't work, so I simply tried replacing `*` with an object, specifying the types. `?React$Element<{ className: string }>` worked just fine, but I can't seem to add an optional `onClick`. I've tried both `onClick?: Function` - a syntax I've seen in some places - and `onClick: ?Function` - as you see below - but both throw the error at the bottom.

```
type RequestDataButtonType = (props: Props) => ?React$Element<{
  className: string,
  onClick: ?Function,
}>

const RequestDataButton
  : RequestDataButtonType
  = ({ requestData, status }) => {
    if (status === Status.REQUESTED) {
      return (
        <div className={css.requested}>
          Contact details requested
        </div>
      )
    } else if (status === Status.ERROR) {
      return (
        <button
          className={css.error}
          onClick={requestData}>
          Error
        </button>
      )
    } else if (status === Status.REQUESTING) {
      return (
        <div className={css.requesting}>
          Requesting contact details
          <LoadIndicator className={css.loadIndicator} />
        </div>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <button
          className={css.request}
          onClick={requestData}>
          Request contact details
        </button>
      )
    }
  }
```

Flow throws the following errors for the above code (ignore line numbers, I've removed some irrelevant code):

```
> flow; test $? -eq 0 -o $? -eq 2

src/content/components/RequestDataButton/RequestDataButton.js:43
 43:         <div className={css.requested}>
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ React element: `div`
 33: type RequestDataButtonType = (props: Props) => ?React$Element<{
                                                                   ^ property `onClick`. Property not found in
 43:         <div className={css.requested}>
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ props of JSX Intrinsic: `div`

src/content/components/RequestDataButton/RequestDataButton.js:57
 57:         <div className={css.requesting}>
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ React element: `div`
 33: type RequestDataButtonType = (props: Props) => ?React$Element<{
                                                                   ^ property `onClick`. Property not found in
 57:         <div className={css.requesting}>
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ props of JSX Intrinsic: `div`


Found 2 errors
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$Shape<T>` to pass the typecheck.

This works:

```
type RequestDataButtonType = (props: Props) => ?React$Element<$Shape<{
  className: string,
  onClick: ?Function,
}>>
```

`$Shape<T>` doesn't require all properties to be defined, but the ones that are defined must match the type definition.

In other words, you're describing any `ReactElement` that can optionally have `onClick`, but - if it does - then it must be a `?Function`.

[Here's a fully working example](https://flowtype.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZygXigbynCBHAVwmWABEBDYcgLigH4AxAgOwGNgBLBZgGihMoFktEnA7MA5lAC+AbgBQoSFABK+IiQpUAQgWDBuAFXDQM8JKjQA+VRHLsAJAFEANhAC2EZsAA8DgMoAFuSQPtisLuTIyABy5J4iwGKSfNwAwi4crADWtIws7FzMMlZW8vKs3CS2hMRklOS6+tzyUFC0arWaDU0GzMaQrehQABTYuF31VHwCwEIyAJToNphDbRwAZqOz82h7UADkExrAEAAmB0urbTc4EHNwxSNrt1A+ZxwAblARUbHxEDQR3UdXOBzKr1eaW4VHYUDO93IHBcqGOoLOL1uPgA9B9PhDXgsXtIoBAUdBNtsqHNLPsDhA4Ig4JcsJi7g8nmy2j4AEZ6Ppcm6-aJxTxAhlMg6CtrpTI5NCYNHdKjSAmQtpORkIOCCnF85rMNU3Im3Elk5AUrYjHa0jDAybiCQs66vXAc0a6vE-SIigFApWcSTg6U1E6On4w+zAeGI5HIEM+ZBgcjFYX-MUHFwIchnAC04g+rEo2oOUGxRqxuK+FagJpuZvJrMhboIjw96re+oFHbaadFgPtJylPagsqy2QVAa05FVIc6Jwj3ijMaocd12K73Brdba0iG0iAA) (I replaced some of your types but the gist is there):

Comment: I'm not quite 100% on how `$Shape` works. It seems to be completely okay with me removing the `?` before `Function`. It's as if it considers every prop in it optional, but if it exists, it has to satisfy the type, not that the type specifies what it is directly (i.e., if it exists or not). Do you know how it works or where I could find out more? Didn't find anything in their docs.

Comment: You can remove if onClick is not optional. And about documentation I started this to address the issue https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2464 Shape is not documented yet, but we're getting there

Comment: Thanks @GabrielePetronella