# How do I specify optional prop types in flow?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype, react-proptypes

I'd like to declare a component in an external library definition (I'm writing flow types for `react-bootstrap`) so that I have optional and required props, and no extra props. I have the following:

```
declare export type AlertProps = {|
  bsClass: bsClass,
  bsStyle: ?bsStyle,
  onDismiss: ?(e: SyntheticEvent) => any,
  closeLabel: ?string,
  style: ?style,
|}

declare export class Alert extends React$Component {
  props: AlertProps;
}
```

(For the sake of this example, lets assume `bsStyle` is actually required.) However, flow still complains if I omit `bsClass`

```
49:     props: AlertProps;
               ^^^^^^^^^^ property `bsClass`. Property not found in
26:       ? (<Alert bsStyle="danger" style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ props of React element `Alert`. See: src/components/audit/AuditAlert.jsx:26
```

If I wrap my props in `$Shape<>`, I cannot have required props. A workaround I have is as follows:

```
declare export type AlertProps = {
  // required props go here
  bsClass: bsClass,
} & $Shape<{|
  // all props (optional and required) go here
  bsClass: bsClass,
  bsStyle: bsStyle,
  onDismiss: (e: SyntheticEvent) => any,
  closeLabel: string,
  style: style,
|}>
```

However, this seems excessively hacky! Is there a better way to achieve my goal?

As a side note, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40884595/how-do-i-specify-an-optional-prop-in-the-returned-reactelement-in-flow) is not answered correctly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can specify optional props by putting a ? after the property name. For example

```
type Props = {
  optionalString?: string,
  maybeString: ?string,
}
```

I can omit optionalString, but if I pass it, it must be a string or undefined. maybeString I must pass, but it's value can be null, undefined, or a string.

You can play with it in an example [here](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiCWBbADrATgF1AEoCmAhgMb6TaxqgDk2pFdorbyuAnhkaAArUMAZ1ABeUAG9ErWBlwpYAOxLQAyrmwpFAcwD8ALlBCNW7QBppoNCU4AjIus07Du40-OIAvsjJLjoAGEaDDFQAAoJUFl5JRVHUzMrG3t4nVBPQwFZIQBKMQA+SUtGXABXbEVwy1YAHiEMEkV8iWiFZTUTHU9JazsHTu1PGuB6xsLQSxyvZBqgzCS+1O1RCUVS6Ghu4HygA)

The docs talk about optional object properties [here](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-optional-object-type-properties).

Comment: Hey TLadd, why is optionalString: undefined a valid value, based on your comment, if its present it can only be a string type ?

Comment: Yeah, good point. undefined is a special case because `{ optionalString: undefined  }.optionalString === undefined` and `{}.optionalString === undefined`. I guess the ? on the property really denotes that accessing the property will return the type or undefined, whether the key is present or not. Updated answer to reflect that.

Comment: I'm getting the `eslint` error: `Unexpected token, expect ","` when trying to declare an optional PropType like this:
`MyComponent.propTypes = { someProp?: PropTypes.bool, ... }` any idea ??